# How to compare '>10' with 11 which is coming as parameter in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table i have. 
[image]

And I need to select agains `Condition` column

```
select * from OfferCondition where Condition = '21'
```

for the above query, it should return 1st and 2nd row.

Comment: Why wouldn't all the rows be returned since they all have `> 10` for the condition?

Comment: sorry.. I missed second row in that ,...... 2nd row is                             122 253 >=20 3 32 2016-04-28 15:21:19 1

Comment: Please edit your question. Only relevant columns are required, and, preferably, no pictures. That said, the obvious solution would be to store only the integer (or a range), or store the integer separate from the operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a HAVING clause for each condition AND the conditions in order (so it stops at the first one... apart from that does as you request I think...

```
SET @iValue = 21;
SELECT substring_index(`Condition`,' ',1) AS Operator,
    substring_index(substring_index(`Condition`,' ',2 ),' ', -1) AS Value
FROM OfferCondition
HAVING (Operator = '>' AND @iValue > Value)
    OR (Operator = '>=' AND @iValue >= Value)
    OR (Operator = '=' AND @iValue = Value)
LIMIT 1;
```

**NOTE** this also requires a space between the operator and operand - as pointed out elsewhere would be much better to include as separate columns